# How to allow admin to add extra unmapped field to a form in real time (Symfony3)

Tags: php, forms, multi-tenant, symfony-3.3

I have a Symfony3 project which facilitates multiple admin/tenants to create custom forms for their users. `TenantData` is the main entity which contains Salutation, firstname and lastname fields. Based on this entity the tenant/admin can create a form `TenantDataType`. Here is what `TenantDataType` looks like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Entity\TenantData;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class TenantDataType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('firstname', TextType::class, array());
        $builder->add('lastname', TextType::class, array());
        $builder->add('title', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Ms' => true,
                'Mr' => false,
            ),
        ));
        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => TenantData::class,
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }

}
```

Now I want the admin to be able to add an extra field without adding an extra column in the TenantData entity. One approach I know is to create a `MetaData` table which contains label, datatype, isrequired and ismultiple fields. Based on this Entity I can create a new form by the name `MetaDataType`. So that the admin can use this form to create an extra field. This basically means that every record of the MetaData table contains the details of an extra field. The problem is how do I use these records to render the extra fields added by the admin/tenant in real time. Since I am creating a new instance of TenantData at the time I am rendering the form and there is no TenantData id at the time which can fetch the related `MetaData` rows. What relationship do I need to establish to get the desired functionality.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you looking to custom your form for admin admin /tenant entity ?

Comment: @ MOHAMMED YASSINE Chabli  Yes

Comment: i gonna show you an example and see if that reply to your need .

Comment: That will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose that your formBuilder as you show above with some modification :

**TenantDataType**

```
 <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use AppBundle\Entity\TenantData;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

    class TenantDataType extends AbstractType {

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

            $builder->add('firstname', TextType::class, array());
            $builder->add('lastname', TextType::class, array());
             if(isset($option['userRole'] && $option['userRole']=="ADMIN_ROLE" ){
             $builder->add('your_admin_field', TextType::class, array());
              }  

            $builder->add('title', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Ms' => true,
                    'Mr' => false,
                ),
            ));
            $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'));
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => TenantData::class,
                'csrf_protection' => true,
                'allow_extra_fields' => true
            ));
        }

    }
```

let's suppose that a tenant user have : TENANT_ROLE

and admin has : ADMIN_ROLE

**Controller**

```
$user_role= // get the user role here . (TENANT_ROLE/ADMIN_ROLE)
    $form = $this->createForm(TenantDataType ::class, $tenantObject, array(
        'userRole' => $user_role,
    );
```

if  you want to access $options array from addEventListener:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $user_role = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions()['userRole'];
}
```